# Can INotifyPropertyChanged affect derived functions

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, inotifypropertychanged

**Update:** My question originally addressed both formatting issues as well as properties "derived" from multiple other properties. I thought it was the same scenario, but as you can see from Fabios answer, this is not the case. I have changed the question a little bit, to make it clear that it is not *just* formatting.

I am using WinForms with one-way data bindings, and INotifyPropertyChanged to update the forms. But I can't figure out excactly how it affects derived functions. For example lets say I have a function which returns a price as a decimal:

```
public decimal price 
{
    get { return _price; }
    set 
    { 
        // Set price and notify that it was changed
        _price = value; 
        InvokePropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("price");
    }
}
```

Another property is responsible for the currency code, which can also be changed:

```
public decimal currency
{
    get { return _currency; }
    set
    {
        _currency = value;
       InvokePropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("currency");
    }
}
```

When the price or currency is changed (set), the property changed function is called. However, I would like this value formatted and with a currency code before I show it in my GUI. So I make my data binding to a derived function:

```
public string formattedPrice
{
    get { return string.Format("{0:n0} {1}", price, currency)
}
```

How will changing the `price` or  `currency` affect the `formattedPrice`? Obviously I have been doing some tests of my own, but I can't really seem to find the logic? The `InvokepropertyChanged` function is defined like this:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
public void InvokePropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null) handler(this, e);
}
```

Comment: There are _many_ ways to approach this. See marked duplicates for a couple of options. Personally, I prefer to keep my INPC properties completely free of custom logic. Instead, I use a base implementation that allows a setter to hook a callback, and in that callback handle property-specific behaviors. And then for something like what you're talking about, to in such a callback just _set_ the "derived" property (an unfortunate word choice IMHO, given that "derived" has a specific, completely unrelated meaning in OOP) to a new value. Yes, there are more backing fields, but the code is simpler.

Comment: @PeterDuniho - I think specific case of this question is related more to the formatting values. Where "related" answers provided by you will lead OP and future readers in wrong direction.

Comment: So this just went from zero to rocket science in no time :-). I am a little confused about what you mean with "keep my INPC properties complete free of custom logic". I am still somewhat new to C#, so I must admit that I am not quite sure excactly how my `InvokePropertyChanged` function works. Could you show it in code?

Comment: @Noceo - _keep my INPC properties completely free of custom logic_ - usually mean that setter should do only two things: `1. Update value; 2. Raise PropertyChanged event for this property.` (In addition you can check is new value same). All other logic should be moved outside of setter(like raisng PropertyChanged event for other properties, or calculate other properties or do something else) If you need to do something else - then you should use commands (`ICommand`).

Comment: @Fabio:  _"this question is related more to the formatting values"_ -- it's not worded that way. I do like the answer you posted, as it does address the formatting-specific scenario. In other APIs, like WPF, formatting is similarly decoupled from the view model property itself. In either case, that's a good thing and good for the OP to see. But SO questions are primarily for future readers; wording is everything, as it governs how the question will be found during web- and site-specific searching. And OP has in fact made clear he wants info beyond just formatting.

Comment: I understand your confusion, as my question addressed both formatting and "derived" properties. It did so because I thought it was the same solution. I see that there is a somewhat easy fix for the formatting part, but the other question still confuses me. Would it be a big "No-go" to make a function which calls `InvokePropertyChanged` for all properties, and just call that from the setters?

Comment: @Noceo - you need raise `PropertyChanged` for all properties you need to be updated in the windows form. Start with raising them in the related setter and when you got working solution(and I hope you will have unit tests for the viewmodels/bounded objects) - you will see "whole picture" and can refactor it by grouping updates in common method where they can be maintained easily. Unit tests will help to do refactoring in fast and secure way.

Comment: @Fabio thanks, I will do that. But what do I do, if the property I am binding to is in a different class than the "base" property (i.e. the property with the setter).

Comment: Without context, difficult to suggest "correct" approach. At least you can "listen" for `PropertyChanged` in that "different class"  and raise own `PropertyChanged` when "base" class will raise `PropertyChanged` for property you listen.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply invoke PropertyChanged for formatted value in setter

```
public decimal price 
{
    get { return _price; }
    set 
    { 
        _price = value; 
        InvokePropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("price");
        InvokePropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("formattedPrice");
    }
}
```

But, because formatting value is more UI(view) responsibility - you can move it to the windows form side by using `Binding.Format` event and leave `price` property as it is.

```
public decimal price 
{
    get { return _price; }
    set 
    { 
        _price = value; 
        InvokePropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("price");
    }
}

// In windows form
var priceBinding = new Binding("Text", sourceObject, "price", true);
priceBinding.Format += (sender, args) => 
{
    var price = (decimal)args.Value;
    args.Value = string.Format("{0:n0} EUR", price);
}

priceTextBox..DataBindings.Add(priceBinding);
```

More about [Binding.Format Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.format(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: That is what I am doing currently. I just wondered if there was a way to avoid manully keeping track of the chaining. In the example I gave it is quite simple, but in larger programs the chains become longer (and branches may occur), and therefore harder to keep track of...

Comment: @Noceo - check updated answer

Comment: Thats quite cool. Actually my question was based on both formatting and properties "derived" from one or more other properties, as I thought the solution was the same. But this fixes my formatting issues at least :-).